# How do I not have a long list of html in the url when implementing a navigation bar?

Tags: python, html, css, django

I have designed a navigation bar using a base.html, styles.css, and main.js.

I have used in it about.html and contact.html through

```
{%block content%}
...
{%endblock%}
```

But when I click on the navigation bar that links me to About, for example, it would go to whichever page I am on (ex. contact page i.e. http://127.0.0.1:8000/contact/) and then add the html (http://127.0.0.1:8000/contact/about.html)

That leads to a lot of urls I have to add to urls.py
(ex. contact/about.html and about/about.html for just getting to the about page)

Is there any way to simplify this?

This is my urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from home.views import about, contact

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('about/', about),
    path('contact/',contact),
]
```

this is my base.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        {% load static %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'home/styles.css' %}">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>{%block name%}{% endblock %}</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <header>
            <nav>
                <div class="logo">
                    <h4>Jinyang Zhang</h4>
                </div>
                <ul class="nav-links">
                    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">My Work</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>

                <div class="burger">
                    <div class="line1"></div>
                    <div class="line2"></div>
                    <div class="line3"></div>
                </div>
            </nav>
            {%block content%}
            {%endblock%}
        </header>
        <script src="{% static 'home/main.js' %}"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I would like it to be, for example, when I click on the navigation "About" from the "Contact" page, it would lead me to http://127.0.0.1:8000/about/ and not http://127.0.0.1:8000/contact/about.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you are hard coding your url's inside the list items. Instead, use the django template system to fix your problem and make your code more maintainable overall:

Instead of:
`<li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>`

change it to something like:
`<li><a href="{% url 'about' %}">About</a></li>`

And in your urls.py name your url:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('about/', about, name="about"),
]
```

Edited: Don't put the .html extension in "{% url %} tag.

As your project grows you can add an app_name to your urls.py file and access the url that way in the django templates.

```
app_name = "appName"
urlpatterns = [
    path('about/', about, name="about"),
]
```

and then in your html:

```
<li><a href="{% url 'appName:about' %}>About</a></li>
'''
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I ended up doing <li><a href="{% url 'about' %}">Home</a></li> and it works!